# Why am I able to access a method without object in java

Tags: java, methods

Here's my code:

```
public class MyProjectPage extends AbstractPage {
    public boolean addDefaultProjectBymyProjects(String softwareName, String projectName,) {
        navigateTomyProjects();
    } 

    public void navigateTomyProjects() {
        clickElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("x.Myprojects.Icon")), "MyProjects");
    }
}
```

I am able to access method `navigateTomyProjects()` without an object; how is this possible?

Note: clickElement is a generic method in abstract page

Answer (score 1):

`navigateTomyProjects()` is an *instance* method.
It is being called from `addDefaultProjectBymyProjects()`, another instance method.

These methods are not being accessed without an object; they are being accessed by `this` - the current instance against which these methods will be executed.

There is nothing mysterious about this code.

Comment: So, let's say I am calling this method navigateTomyProjects  from main method, then it is giving me error, is main not considered as instance method?

Comment: @LokeshS, non-static, or instance methods cannot be called from static methods. `main()` is a static method.

Answer (score 1):

Both the methods `navigateTomyProjects()` and `addDefaultProjectBymyProjects()` reside as *instance methods* in the same class. As a result, either of the methods can access the other method without explicitly creating an object of the class.

To be more precise, `addDefaultProjectBymyProjects()` calls `navigateTomyProjects()` internally as `this.navigateTomyProjects()`. Here, the `this` keyword refers to the current object (invoking object).

Comment: So, let's say I am calling this method navigateTomyProjects from main method, then it is giving me error, main cannot add this keyword to call that method?

Comment: Irrespective of whether the main() method is in the same class or a different class, in Java, the main method is declared as `public static void main(String[] args)`. Here, as you can observe, the main() method is `static` meaning it does not belong to any object of the class but to the class itself. On the other hand, the other methods are `instance methods`, **not** `static methods`. Static methods cannot access non-static methods with creating an object of the class.

Comment: Can you give any reference link to read about why can't we access static methods from non-static

Comment: These are some of the links I came across on a quick Google search.

1. [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

2. [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

3. [http://www.lysator.liu.se/java/progGuide/java/anatomy/static.html](http://www.lysator.liu.se/java/progGuide/java/anatomy/static.html)